# Swift - Concatenate buttons like a paragraph with text wrap

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dynamic array with 5-6 elements. From that I need to create buttons dynamically:

```
func buildTopicButtons(with topics: [Topic]) {
    
    var counter = 0
    for topic in topics {
        let topicBut = TopicButton() // a subclass of UIButton
        topicBut.setTitle(topic.topicName, for: .normal)
        topicBut.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: 15)
        topicBut.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: "myColor"), for: .normal)
        topicBut.backgroundColor = nil
        topicBut.tag = counter
        topicBut.topicId = topic.topicId
        
        //constraints code here

        topicBut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToTopic(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        counter += 1
        
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have these buttons appear like so:

Topic1 · Topic2 · Topic3 · Topic 4

If they reach the end of the screen they need to go to a second line.

I've thought of adding an empty view and then add the buttons to it:

```
buttonsContainerView.addSubView(topicBut)
```

But don't know how to set up constraints within a loop to have them go one after the other and then to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any automatic way to do what you describe. You could set up a UICollectionView to organize your buttons that way, but that would mean creating a collection view with a data source and a custom flow layout - a fair effort if you're not familiar with collection views.

My suggestion would be to create a custom view that manages a pair of horizontal stack views, and has methods to add and remove buttons. It would figure out when the top stack view was full and start adding buttons to the bottom stack view.